# How to make regular expression only accept special formula?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, regex

I'm making html page for special formula using angularJS.

```
<input ng-model="expression" type="text" ng-blur="checkFormula()" />

function checkFormula() {
  let regex;

  if (scope.formulaType === "sum") {
    regex = "need sum regular expression here"; // input only like as 1, 2, 5:6, 8,9
  } else {
    regex = "need arithmetic regular expression here"; // input only like as 3 + 4 + 6 - 9
  }
  
  if (!regex.test(scope.expression)) {
    // show notification error
    Notification.error("Please input expression correctly");
    return;
  }
  
  // success case
  if (scope.formulaType === "sum") {
     let fields = expression.split(',');
     let result = fields.reduce((acc, cur) => { return acc + Number(cur) }, 0);
     // processing result
  } else {
     // need to get fields with + and - sign.
     // TODO: need coding more...
     let result = 0;
     // processing result
  }
}
```

So I want to make inputbox only accept my formula.
Formulas are two cases.

```
1,2,3:7,9
```

or

```
4-3+1+5
```

First case, means sum(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9) and second case means (4-3+1+5).

But I don't know regular expression how to process it.
I searched google, but I didn't get result for my case.

So I want to need 2 regex match.

Comment: Do you want 1 regex to match them both or 2 regex to match them separately?

Comment: needs two regex to match them separately.

Comment: Are decimal points/negative numbers allowed? Or only positive integers?

Comment: Only positive numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
1,2,3:7,9
```

Fot this pattern, you can try [this one](https://regex101.com/r/APhWQQ/3/):

```
^\d+(?::\d+)?(?:,\d+(?::\d+)?)*$
```

- `^\d+(?::\d+)?`

> matches string starts with a number(e.g. `1`) or two numbers separated by a column (e.g. `1:2`)

- `(?:,\d+(?::\d+)?)*$`

> repeats the previous pattern with a comma in front of it as many time as possible until meets the end of the string (e.g. `,2:3,4:5,6`)

---

```
4-3+1+5
```

Fot this pattern, you can try [this one](https://regex101.com/r/10bRvW/1/):

```
^\d+(?:[+-]\d+)*$
```

- Like the previous one, this is much simpler
- `^\d+`

> starts with a number(e.g. `12`)

- `(?:[+-]\d+)*$`

> repeats the previous pattern with a `-` or `+` in front of it as many time as possible until meets the end of the string (e.g. `+2-3+14`)

---

Also, if you need at least one pair of numbers.

Such as `1,2` is allowed but just `1` is not. You can just change the `*` before `$` to `+`:

```
^\d+(?::\d+)?(?:,\d+(?::\d+)?)+$
```

```
^\d+(?:[+-]\d+)+$
```

And if you allow white spaces in between them:

```
^\d+(?:\s*:\s*\d+)?(?:\s*,\s*\d+(?:\s*:\s*\d+)?)+$
```

```
^\d+(?:\s*[+-]\s*\d+)+$
```